# How to Sort Date on TitleForHeaderInSection

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, sorting

I have program as below: ..- However, I want to sort the data descending by date in the TitleForHeaderInSection, and also want to format the date in the Header as

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
//    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy"];
NSDate *headerDate = (NSDate *)[managedObject valueForKey:@"dateCreated"];
NSString *headerTitle = [formatter stringFromDate:headerDate];
```

Here is the Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"List of Items"];

    NSURL *serverURL = [NSURL URLWithString:SERVER_URL];
    [[DataManager sharedInstance] loadData:serverURL withCompletion:^(NSArray *itemListArray, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Server Error" message:@"Unable to fetch Data from Server" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [errorAlertView show];
        }
        else {
            fetchData = [self convertSectionTableData:itemListArray keyString:@"date"];
            [self.listTableView reloadData];
        }
    }];
    [self.listTableView reloadData];}


- (NSMutableDictionary *)convertSectionTableData:(NSArray *)convertDataSet keyString:(NSString *)keyString {
    NSMutableDictionary *outputData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSString *key = NULL;
    for (NSDictionary *dic in convertDataSet) {

        if (key == NULL) {
            key = [dic objectForKey:keyString];
        } else if (key != [dic objectForKey:keyString]) {
            [outputData setValue:temp forKey:key];
            temp = [NSMutableArray array];

            key = [dic objectForKey:keyString];
        }

        if ([[dic objectForKey:keyString] isEqualToString: key]) {
            [temp addObject:dic];
        }

        if (dic == [convertDataSet lastObject]) {
            [outputData setValue:temp forKey:key];
        }
    }

    return outputData;}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [fetchData count];}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[fetchData allValues][section] count];}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CustomListTableCell";

    CustomListTableCell *cell = (CustomListTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    int section = (int)indexPath.section;
    int row = (int)indexPath.row;

    NSDictionary *data = [[fetchData allValues][section] objectAtIndex:row];

    cell.homeLabel.text = [data objectForKey:@"home"];

    return cell;}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [fetchData allKeys][section];}

@end
```

Comment: can you add your data format ?

Comment: What currently does your code? I mean what works and what don't?

Comment: This is the Data that I want to retrieve: http://borindatabase.000webhostapp.com/jsonData.php

The data was retrieved perfectly, but it does not sort correctly. And I do not know how to format the date in the TitleForHeaderInSection in a way like this: Mon, 3 Jul 2017

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that dictionaries are unordered, so you need some way to retrieve them in the correct order. I might suggest building a sorted array of the keys of the dictionary.

```
// build dictionary of objects, keyed by date

NSMutableDictionary *objectsForDates = ...

// build sorted array of dates in descending order

NSArray *dates = [[objectsForDates allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id _Nonnull obj1, id _Nonnull obj2) {
    return [obj2 compare:obj1];
}];
```

You can then use this `dates` object to represent the "sections" of your table view and then use that to know which entry in your dictionary to return:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.dates count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.objectsForDates[self.dates[section]] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.formatter stringFromDate:self.dates[section]];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Location *object = self.objectsForDates[self.dates[indexPath.section]][indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = object.home;
    return cell;
}
```

---

Note, I would suggest a couple of unrelated changes to your code:

1. I'd suggest using a custom object type to contents of your JSON. This offers stronger typing than a simple `NSDictionary`.

   I'd also make sure that the types are more naturally typed (e.g. the `id` looks like it should be a `NSInteger`; the `date` looks like it should be a `NSDate`).

   I'd also give this custom type an `initWithDictionary` initializer, to simplify the parsing code.
2. The logic for building the dictionary keyed by date (your `convertSectionTableData`) can be simplified a bit.
3. Your date formatter for the UI should not use `locale` of `en_US`. Your formatter that's parsing the JSON should (or more accurately, it should use `en_US_POSIX`), but when presenting the format in the UI, you should use the users' own locale.

   Your date formatter for the UI also should not use a fixed `dateFormat` string. Either use one of the pre-existing `dateStyle`, or if you must use `dateFormat`, build a localized version using `dateFormatFromTemplate`.

Anyway, pulling that together, you get something like:

```
@interface Location : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger identifier;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *home;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *date;

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
@end

@implementation Location

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.identifier = [dictionary[@"id"] integerValue];
        self.home = dictionary[@"home"];
        [self setDateFromString:dictionary[@"date"]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setDateFromString:(NSString *)string {
    static NSDateFormatter *formatter;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
        formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
        formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
    });

    self.date = [formatter dateFromString:string];
}
@end
```

And

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *objectsForDates;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dates;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDateFormatter *formatter;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // set formatter for output

    self.formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [self.formatter setDateFormat:[NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"EEEdMMMyyyy" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]];
    self.formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];

    // perform request

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://borindatabase.000webhostapp.com/jsonData.php"];
    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error || !data) {
            NSLog(@"networkError: %@", error);
            return;
        }

        NSError *parseError;
        NSArray *values = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
        if (![values isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            NSLog(@"parseError: %@", parseError);
        }

        // build dictionary of objects, keyed by date

        NSMutableDictionary *objectsForDates = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        for (NSDictionary *value in values) {
            Location *object = [[Location alloc] initWithDictionary:value];
            NSMutableArray *objects = objectsForDates[object.date];
            if (!objects) {
                objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                objectsForDates[object.date] = objects;
            }
            [objects addObject:object];
        }

        // build sorted array of dates in descending order

        NSArray *dates = [[objectsForDates allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id _Nonnull obj1, id _Nonnull obj2) {
            return [obj2 compare:obj1];
        }];

        // now update UI

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.objectsForDates = objectsForDates;
            self.dates = dates;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });

    }] resume];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.dates count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.objectsForDates[self.dates[section]] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.formatter stringFromDate:self.dates[section]];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Location *object = self.objectsForDates[self.dates[indexPath.section]][indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = object.home;
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Mr. Rob. The dictionaries has been sorted, but I would preferred to be sorted Descending. I want the most recent date (Mon, Jun 25 2017) to be on the top and the oldest date (Mon, Jun 5 2017) to be at the bottom. And one more I would like to fetch the data 20 row in one time.. and then continue to fetch another 20 row more when we scroll reach the bottom line.
Thank you on your kind support..

Comment: If you want it sorted in descending order, swap `obj1` and `obj2` in the `sortedArrayUsingComparator`, like I have in the revised answer. In terms of fetching the rows 20 at a time, the above was predicated on the assumption that you were downloading all of the records. The challenge in paging is that this will mess up your sorting. If you want to do paged fetching, you need to (a) change the web service to sort them for you; (b) change your client code to not sort, but merely aggregate them into sections; (c) change your web service to take additional page parameters parameters.

Comment: Thanks you Mr. Rob.. it's very challenging.. Do you have any sample or tutorials regarding this? Please advise.. Thanks

Comment: No, I can't think of any off the top of my head. First, I'd ask yourself how many you're likely to have in this list. If a few hundred, I'd suggest you don't worry about paging. Too much hassle for not enough benefit. But if you're talking tens or hundreds of thousands of rows, then maybe paging is worth it. First, change service to sort the results (or allow you to specify the order that they should be sorted.). Then implement paging in the web service. Only then should you even start to worry about client-side changes to support paging.